# Specifying hex-escaped character followed by a literal hex digit

Tags: c++, string, hex, string-literals

The following program...

```
int main () {
    const char str1[] = "\x1bK"; // intent: \x1b followed by 'K'
    const char str2[] = "\x1bE"; // intent: \x1b followed by 'E'
    const char str3[] = "\x1b0"; // intent: \x1b followed by '0'
}
```

...generates the following compiler warnings for `str2` and `str3` in [all compilers I checked](https://godbolt.org/z/7x4WjMsee):

```
warning: hex escape sequence out of range
```

My intent is to declare three two-character long strings:

- `str1`: `\x1b` + `K`
- `str2`: `\x1b` + `E`
- `str3`: `\x1b` + `0`

But instead its parsing the last two as if *1be* and *1b0* were the specified hex codes.

This seems to happen any time `\x??` is followed by a third perceived hexadecimal digit.

In a string literal, how can I specify a character with `\x`, followed by another character, if that character is also a hexadecimal digit?

I feel like this is a really silly question, but somehow I've never been in this situation before.

Comment: `const char str2[] = "\x1b""E";`

Comment: That warning is correct: `\x` consumes **all** of the subsequent hex digits. It doesn't know or care how its value is being used.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate; thanks for the links.

Comment: Note with C++23 soon in the mix: `"\x{1b}E"`

Comment: @chris Thank you for pointing this out. If I understand correctly [that page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), in C++23 we can also write `"\N{ESC}E"` which might be slightly more readable.

Comment: @prapin, Yes, this is one of those cases where a name would be far clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply have the compiler concatenate 2 separate string literals.

```
int main () {
    const char str1[] = "\x1b" "K";
    const char str2[] = "\x1b" "E";
    const char str3[] = "\x1b" "0";
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't need to do it.

Comment: @273K -- no, not strictly needed, but it makes the parallel structure clearer.